# Insert Column Name into its Value using R

Tags: r, text, dplyr, data.table, reshape2

I need to insert Column Name, Department, into its value. i have code like here:

```
Department <- c("Store1","Store2","Store3","Store4","Store5")
Department2 <- c("IT1","IT2","IT3","IT4","IT5")
x <- c(100,200,300,400,500)
Result <- data.frame(Department,Department2,x)
Result
```

The expected result is like:

```
Department <- c("Department_Store1","Departmentz_Store2","Department_Store3","Department_Store4","Department_Store5")
Department2 <- c("Department2_IT1","Department2_IT2","Department2_IT3","Department2_IT4","Department2_IT5")
x <- c(100,200,300,400,500)
Expected.Result <- data.frame(Department,Department2,x)
Expected.Result
```

Can somebody help? Thanks

Comment: use `paste` i.e. `Result$Department <- paste(names(Result)[1], Result$Department, sep="_")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you gather the column names in question into a vector `dep_col`, this is a clean `base R` solution with a for loop:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:5,
                 Department = paste0("Store", 1:5),
                 Department2 = paste0("IT", 1:5))

dep_col <- names(df)[-1]

for (c in dep_col)
  df[[c]] <- paste(c, df[[c]], sep = "_")
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way with `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Convert to character to avoid warning message, will convert all columns to character
Result[] <- lapply(Result, as.character)

Result %>%
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>% # optional, only convert factor to character, retain all other types
  gather(key, value, -x) %>% 
  mutate(var = paste(key, value, sep = "_")) %>% 
  select(-value) %>% 
  spread(key,var)

    x        Department     Department2
1 100 Department_Store1 Department2_IT1
2 200 Department_Store2 Department2_IT2
3 300 Department_Store3 Department2_IT3
4 400 Department_Store4 Department2_IT4
5 500 Department_Store5 Department2_IT5
```

Data:

```
Result <- data.frame(
  Department = c("Store1","Store2","Store3","Store4","Store5"),
  Department2 = c("IT1","IT2","IT3","IT4","IT5"),
  x = c(100,200,300,400,500)
)
```

Comment: Thanks you. it helps me, but if i have 10 departments with different value. Department with Store (like above), Department with IT, Department with Financial, etc. How should i do? Of course i can't do it one by one. Thanks before

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, could you update the question with data that shows the code above failing to produce your desired output? If for example, row 1 in `Department` had a value of IT, the code above should return `Department_IT` for row 1. Is that what you want?

Comment: Hi sir, i have updated my data. Could you help me to solve this? thanks

Comment: Updated my answer, let me know if that's what your want

Comment: Thanks sir.. Amazing Job, Thank You so much :)

Comment: Hello sir, i try with more data but i get this error message "Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows". How should i do sir? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to prepend the values in all columns starting with `"Department"` by the respective column name.

**Edit** By request of the OP, the code to select columns has been generalized to pick additional column names.

Here is a solution using `data.table`'s fast `set()` function:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Result)
cols <- stringr::str_subset(names(Result), "^(Department|Division|Team)")
for (j in cols) {
  set(Result, NULL, j, paste(j, Result[[j]], sep = "_"))
}
Result
```

> ```
>           Department     Department2   x
> 1: Department_Store1 Department2_IT1 100
> 2: Department_Store2 Department2_IT2 200
> 3: Department_Store3 Department2_IT3 300
> 4: Department_Store4 Department2_IT4 400
> 5: Department_Store5 Department2_IT5 500
> ```

Note that `set()` updates by reference, i.e., without copying the whole object.

Comment: Hi, For real my data is not always starting with Department sir, it can be started with Division, Team etc. Department is a sample. Could you make it more general sir? Thanks

Comment: Code has been generalized. You may add more stuff at your discretion by using the `|` operator.