# How to make a column out of a column name its value?

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have below data

```
df<- data_frame(State= c('CA', 'IN', 'CHI'),
       Age= c(46,29,32),
       Status= c('Employed', '', 'Employed')
       )
```

In the end, I want to create data that looks like this:

```
df<- data_frame(col1= c('State-CA', 'State-IN', 'State-CHI'),
       col2= c('Age-46','Age-29','Age-32'),
       col3= c('Status-Employed', '', 'Status-Employed')
       )
```

Connecting the name of a column and its value with a dash. If a value is missing, the column name shouldn't connect to the value of the table. Could anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `imap`, it is a single step.  As `data.frame`s are named `list` with columns of equal `length`, the `imap` loops over the `list`, with the anonymous function call (`~`), get the `.y` as the column name and the values as `.x`, then `paste` it with `str_c`

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
imap_dfc(df, ~ case_when(.x ==""|is.na(.x) ~ as.character(.x), TRUE ~ str_c(.y, .x, sep='-')))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  State     Age    Status         
#  <chr>     <chr>  <chr>          
#1 State-CA  Age-46 Status-Employed
#2 State-IN  Age-29 ""      
#3 State-CHI Age-32 Status-Employed
```

---

In `base R`

```
df[] <- Map(function(x, y) ifelse(x=="", x, paste(x, y, sep="-")),df, names(df))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for has been answered on this thread - [Insert Column Name into its Value using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49173202/insert-column-name-into-its-value-using-r). Hope you find this helpful!

Also, this code should work for you -

```
col_names <- names(df)
for (c in col_names) {
  df[[c]] <- ifelse(df[[c]] != "", paste(c, df[[c]], sep = "-"), "")
}
df
```

Output -

```
 State    Age          Status
1 State-CA Age-46 Status-Employed
2 State-IN Age-29                
3 State-CHI Age-32 Status-Employed
```