# replace cell values greater than 0 with column name

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a dataframe with the following structure:

```
Df = data.frame(
  Col1 = c(1,0,0),
  Col2 = c(0,2,1),
  Col3 = c(0,0,0)
)
```

What I'm trying to get is a dataframe where those cells with a value greater than 0 get replaced with the column name and those lower than 1 get replaced by NA. The resulting dataframe would be something like this:

```
Df = data.frame(
      Col1 = c("Col1",NA,NA),
      Col2 = c(NA,"Col2","Col2"),
      Col3 = c(NA,NA,NA)
    )
```

So far I tried with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49173202/insert-column-name-into-its-value-using-r) and with functions like `apply()`, `mutate_if()`, and `across()` but I can't get what I'm after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
Df %>%
 mutate(across(everything(), ~ if_else(. > 0, cur_column(), NA_character_)))

  Col1 Col2 Col3
1 Col1 <NA> <NA>
2 <NA> Col2 <NA>
3 <NA> Col2 <NA>
```